# imagemagick produces undesired output image

Tags: imagemagick

I am running ImageMagick 7.0.8-27 Q16 x64. I have a text file `text.txt` with pixel information properly formatted for working with `imagemagick`. The first five lines of the text file are as below:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4960,4960,65535,srgb
0,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
1,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
2,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
3,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
```

I want to be able to convert the textfile into an image but it would seem I'm getting an incorrect output image.When from the command line I run

```
magick convert text.txt image.jpg
```

I get an image but not the one I want. To confirm that `imagemagick` has indeed given me a bad image, I run

```
magick convert image.jpg text2.txt
```

and to my surprise, this text file `text2.txt` is different from the original `text.txt` which was used to produce the image. The first five lines are as below:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4960,4960,65535,srgb
0,0: (65278,65278,65535)  #FEFEFF  srgb(254,254,255)
1,0: (65278,65278,65535)  #FEFEFF  srgb(254,254,255)
2,0: (65278,65278,65535)  #FEFEFF  srgb(254,254,255)
3,0: (65278,65278,65535)  #FEFEFF  srgb(254,254,255)
```

Why is `imagemagick` messing up the pixel information when creating the image? I am on Windows 8.1.

Comment: First thing I would do is try saving as a png to see if jpg compression is the problem

Comment: I will try it out and let you know how it goes

Comment: When using version 7 you should only need magick and not magick convert. I believe if you use magick convert it calls a V6 legacy version instead of V7.

Answer (score 0):

**You did not identify your Imagemagick version.**

This works fine for me on IM 7.0.8.58 Q16 Mac OSX.

*Note for IM 7, use magick, not magick convert and not simply convert.*

File - text.txt

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,srgb
0,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
1,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
2,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
3,0:    (65278,65278,65278) #FEFEFE srgb(254,254,254)
```

```
magick text.txt text2.txt
```

or

```
magick TXT:text.txt TXT:text2.txt
```

File - text2.txt

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (65278,65278,65278)  #FEFEFEFEFEFE  srgb(254,254,254)
1,0: (65278,65278,65278)  #FEFEFEFEFEFE  srgb(254,254,254)
2,0: (65278,65278,65278)  #FEFEFEFEFEFE  srgb(254,254,254)
3,0: (65278,65278,65278)  #FEFEFEFEFEFE  srgb(254,254,254)
```

**Your problem is that you saved your txt file to JPG. JPG is a lossy compressed format and changes pixels values due to the compression and losses.** Try saving to PNG or TIFF (or any other lossless compression format). Then convert that to .txt again. That is what user Bonzo suggested.

For example:

```
magick text.txt text.png
magick text.png text2.txt
```

produces text2.txt as

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,gray
0,0: (65278)  #FEFEFE  gray(254)
1,0: (65278)  #FEFEFE  gray(254)
2,0: (65278)  #FEFEFE  gray(254)
3,0: (65278)  #FEFEFE  gray(254)
```

which is also correct.

Comment: What exactly does ```magick text.txt text2.txt``` do? Did you mean ```magick text.txt image.jpg```?

Comment: The command takes one .txt image and reads it into a miff format and then writes the miff back to another .txt output file. See my addition to my answer.